# Find Largest Subset with closest average and standard deviation to given values

Tags: algorithm

I have the following problem and I am looking for an efficient solution.

Lets consider a set of 100 integers. I want to find the largest subset of values that will have the closest average and std to some given values (say `av` and `std`).

The solution I see is to compute all possible combinations and then choose the one that is the closest in terms of the sum of distances to avg and std deviation (i.e the sum of the distance between the average of thesample and the given average + the distance between standard deviation of the sample and the given standard deviation is the smallest (each sum having a weight)).
But this soution is really slow, I was thinking about some dynamic programming solution.
For each `n` (`n` -number of elements in the subset we find the best fitting solution). Then, we compare each best solution and from this moment we can apply some custom criterias to choose between  best solution of different cardinality

Any hints?

**Edit**

Thank you very much for your answers. 
Indeed, asstated in the question, the mean and standard deviation are independent of the initial set `X`. 
The criteria to define is in terms of L²- norm. 
Moreover I believe that a even better norm would be a "modified L2 norm giving each componenet a weight i.e : 
   `

> sqrt( sum|w_i x_i|²)

` - where W_i are weigths defined by the user.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the best objective function: I think it will often give answers consisting of exactly 2 values (the same distance either side of the desired average, and far enough away from it to give about the desired stdev).  Is that what you want?

Comment: How exactly do you define being close to the two desired values? L2-norm, or something else?

Comment: To expand on @MvG a bit - if you can create a subset that exactly matches your expected mean, but misses the stddev, OR you can create a subset that exactly matches the stddev, but is off on the mean, which would be the better solution? You need some sort of metric that defines what it means for a (sub-)set to match two things, because that's not a well-defined concept otherwise...